# How to catch an ouppuit of a process or a command

Tags: docker, field, rules, falco

I'm trying to write a rule where the condition depends on the output of a script.sh. I had tried several approaches, but I did not have success.

Searching in your documentation but didn´t find anything that help me. I tried several evt or proc, but neither of them given me any info.

In fact, this is the rule with I'm trying to see how I can find a workaround:

```
- rule: FIM Custom rule
  desc: Testing rule
  condition: access_log_files and (evt.type=close)
  output: Test result (proc_name=%proc.name command=%proc.cmdline evt_type=%evt.type evt.args =%evt.args syslog_.facility_str=%syslog.facility.str syslog_message=%syslog.message)
  priority: WARNING
```

Consider please that I´m running Falco on Docker with the last image.

When I execute in the Ubuntu host the command logger test, I recievedin the stdout of the docker falco container this message:

{"hostname":"dc95654c63c3","output":"01:21:29.759239580: Warning Test result (proc_name=python3 command=python3 /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/timer.py evt_type=close evt.args =res=0  syslog_.facility_str= syslog_message=)","priority":"Warning","rule":"FIM Custom rule","source":"syscall","tags":[],"time":"2022-12-17T01:21:29.759239580Z", "output_fields": {"evt.args":"res=0 ","evt.time":1671240089759239580,"evt.type":"close","proc.cmdline":"python3 /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/timer.py","proc.name":"python3","syslog.facility.str":null,"syslog.message":null}}

So please tell me what I can do.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, a note re: "your" documentation -- Stack Overflow is a much larger community; you're not communicating principally (or even primarily) with Sysdig/Falco staff here

Answer (score 0):

In order to feed Falco with external sources of events (those that are not Kernel Syscalls) you'd need to use a [Falco plugin](https://falco.org/docs/plugins/). There are plugins to obtain events from Kubernetes, AWS CloudTrail, or even from GitHub. However, there is no plugin, that I know of, to obtain information from the standard output of a program or from Syslog.

Due to the nature of the project Falco, anyone in the community can contribute with such a plugin, so I invite you to join the [Falco slack channel](https://kubernetes.slack.com/messages/falco) and ask around, or even write [your own plugin](https://falco.org/blog/extend-falco-inputs-with-a-plugin-the-basics/).